To prove the existence of solution of a highly nonlinear ODE.
I want to study
$$
 \cot \theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \theta^2}=e^u.
$$
Which is highly nonlinear, I have no idea about how to solve it or prove the existence of solution with appropriate boundary condition because I am not very familiar with the tools in ODE. Do you have some ideas?
Actually I can solve
$$
\cot \theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \theta^2}=0,
$$
but the exponential part seems to be the most difficult to handle.

The solution process for pde's very much depends on the boundary conditions. For example,  on a finite interval Fourier series might be used, on a half line Laplace transform and on the whole real line Fourier transform. Maybe share your solution(which contains boundary conditions?) for the homogeneous eqn?

If you are interested in the existence of solutions, I suggest to rewrite the whole equation as a planar ODE (an ODE in $\mathbb{R}^2$). This can be done by calling, for example, $x_1=u$ and $x_2=\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}$.
Then, you have a vector field $f:(0, \pi)\times \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$, and you can check if it satisfies the hypothesis of the Cauchy-Lipschitz existence theorem... or the existence-of-solutions theorem you are familiar with...
